# PNPM monorepo with NuxtJS & NestJS

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js, nestjs, vite, pnpm-workspace

Hello fellow developer,

While creating a basic pnpm monorepo  with two folders in a workspace:

- packages with an app folder housing a **NuxtJS** app
- services with an app folder housing a **NestJS** app

I encountered an **500 error** with the following message:

**[vite-node] [ERR_LOAD_URL] /Shared/FooEnum**

within the **NuxtJS** app while trying to access shared files from the services/app folder in the **about.vue** component.

```
<template>
  <h1>About page</h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { BarEnum, FooEnum } from "@hgtronic/service-app/src/Shared/Enums";
console.log("foo enum " + FooEnum.Foo1);
console.log("bar enum " + BarEnum.Bar1);
</script>
```

I've created a repository under this [link](https://github.com/HGtronic/awesome-project), I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you for reading.

My goal is to access shared files from the sevices/app folder.

I've looked at all **tsconfig.json** files in the project but I couldn't find the reason for the error.

Perhaps I need to adjust **nuxt.config.ts** file?